# How do I extract text in between "<>"

Tags: c#

I've been trying extract text from a text file if they are not between a "<>". At the same time, I want the extracted words to be printed on a new line.

This is the Question: `Write a program that extracts from an XML file the text only (without the tags)`

Sample Input: 
`<?xml version="1.0"><student><name>Peter</name><age>21</age><interests count="3"><interest>Games</interest><interest>C#</interest>`

Desired Output:

`Peter
21
Games
C#
Java`

my current input is like this:

```
Peter

21


 Games

C#

 Java
```

There are empty lines in between.

This is what my code looks like at the moment. Any help would be appreciated! 
And if you were wondering, this is self study-homework. So I don't need hand this in. I'm not cheating.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Chapter_15_Question_10
    {
        class Program
        {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This app extracts the words not in tags");

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(
            @"C:\Users\Nate\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Chapter 15\Chapter 15 Question 10\Chapter 15 Question 10\TextFile1.txt");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (reader)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadToEnd();
            bool isOpen = false;
            for (int i = 1; i < line.Length; i++)
            {

                if (line[i-1] == '<')
                {
                    isOpen = true;
                }

                if (line[i-1] == '>')
                {
                    isOpen = false;
                }

                if (isOpen)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (!(isOpen) && (line[i] != '<'))
                    Console.Write(line[i]);
                if(line[i] == '<')
                    Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can do a `xml deserialization`, would make your life a lot easier, looks like homework, so you should do the rest yourself :)

Comment: To continue on what AD.Net said, here is a helpful MSDN article for you: [XML Processing Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669131(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Does the solution require you to manually parse the XML or can you use tools that already exist?

Comment: This question came from  a chapter on handing in text files so i preferably have to manually parse the XML. Sorry if I didn't make that clear

Comment: Hit it with a debugger and trace it out youself

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to parse the XML yourself by reading line by line and parsing the delimiters. .NET offers a range of classes that allows you read XML.

What you are looking for are Text nodes.

Assuming this XML

```
var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><student><name>Peter</name><age>21</age><interests count=\"3\"><interest>Games</interest><interest>C#</interest></interests></student>";
```

This version uses the more recent `System.Xml.Linq` namespace, where you use Linq flavoured queries to read your XML.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); // Use XDocument.Load instead of parse to read from a file
foreach (var text in doc.DescendantNodes().Where(n => n.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Text))
{
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

While this version uses the `System.Xml` namespace where you can use XPath to write a query.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml); // Use doc.Load to read from a file
foreach (XmlNode text in doc.SelectNodes("//text()"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(text.Value);
}
```

Comment: The only reason I'm using this method is because I have yet to learn Linq been exposed to XML itself. This homework was in the chapter on handling text files. I should have made that clearer! My bad. hehe

Comment: The second version using XmlDocument doesn't use Linq, but it uses the original XmlDocument. Now if your homework specify that you shouldn't use the Xml classes at all, that is something else.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with others you should use one of the .NET XML classes, I assume this is homework and maybe your teacher doesn't want you to. So here is your code, modified:

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++) {
    if (line[i] == '<') {
        isOpen = true;
    }
    else if (line[i] == '>') {
        isOpen = false;
    }
    else if (!isOpen) {
        Console.Write(line[i]);
        if (i < line.length - 1 && '<' == line[i+1]) {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: line[i+1] could give and index out of range

Comment: @Paparazzi Yes, I thought of that, but assumed the xml would be well formatted and always end in a closing tag. But I will fix. This code is not very robust and shouldn't be used in the "real world" but since it's homework, I just addressed what was given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use for Regex:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegexTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string pattern = @"(?<=>)[^<]+(?=<)";
            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            string example = @"<?xml version=""1.0""><student><name>Peter</name><age>21</age><interests count=""3""><interest>Games</interest><interest>C#</interest>";
            MatchCollection results = rgx.Matches(example);
            foreach (Match m in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Peter
21
Games
C#
```

It will return any text that is between `>` and `<`, as long as there is at least one character.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the same homework task a few years ago. So, my former solution doesn't look so good right now. As the idea is to exercise "manual" text parsing I could suggest the following approach with more usage of string operations:

```
        using (reader)
        {
            var text = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // Text is found between > and < tags
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                // Find first and last index of the substring to be extracted
                if (text[i] == '>' && text[i + 1] != '<')
                {
                    int textFirstIndex = i + 1;

                    // Handle border case
                    if (textFirstIndex == text.Length - 1)
                    {
                        sb.Append(text.Substring(textFirstIndex, 1));
                        break;
                    }

                    int textLastIndex = text.IndexOf('<', textFirstIndex + 1);

                    // Extract substring
                    sb.AppendLine(text.Substring(textFirstIndex, textLastIndex - textFirstIndex));
                    i = textLastIndex;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString().TrimEnd());
```

I emphasize that this is not the optimal solution, but it is appropriate for educational purposes like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you would take the effort to trace it out
the sequence

```
><
```

Will cause a line feed EVERY time

```
bool writeON = false;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char c in line)
{
    if (c == '>')
        writeON = true;
    else  if (c == '<')
    {
        writeON = false;
        if (sb.Length > 0)
            Debug.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        sb.Clear();
    }
    else if (writeON)
        sb.Append(c);
}
Debug.WriteLine("ddonce");
```